# Display issue macbook pro 2017 touchbar

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

I have issue with the display on my macbook pro 15 in 2017 touch bar.

When I boot or restart the device there is some noise in the screen. After osx start the screen back to normal.

I did rest SMC & NVRAM, also run the safe mode, still the issue is appearing.

I have already contact apple support they said I need to bring it to apple store to fix it, yet there is no official apple store in my country, I need to travel in order to visit apple store.

Can anyone help me to solve it

[image: screen issue]

Comment: Happened to me, had to get display replaced.

Comment: Wouldn't they replace the whole mac?

Comment: no. they typically take for around 10 days, depending on the issue, they will either replace the logic board, or just the display, possibly both. You may have data loss, so make sure you back everything up before service. If you have Apple Care, it will be free, if you don't have Apple Care, then get it, as the repair costs close to $1000 CAD (around 780 us)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I went to them they replaced the screen only and now it is fine.

Comment: They did the same with mine. Cheers!